# How to access the node created in user space from kernel?

Tags: linux, drivers, alsa

I am doing an exercise in which I want to access the node `/dev/snd/controlC0` of the sound card from the kernel to set up the tinymix control from the kernel space instead of user space using a tinymix utility. Now from the flow of the tinymix utility I have found that at the start its execution it will call a `mixer_open()` function from the user space which internally calls the `snd_ctl_open()` function of the kernel.Now as I have to do the same thing from kernel my module need to call the same function. The issue what I am facing is function `snd_ctl_open()` have arguments `struct inode *inode, struct file *file`. So how can I get the inode information of the node in my module?

The file `mixer.c` is located in the Android AOSP code at `external/tinyalsa/mixer.c`. `snd_ctl_open()` is located in the Linux kernel at `sound/core/control.c`.

I found one in build kernel API `filp_open()` which can do the task above mentioned but it can be used after the file system mount only. I want to open a node before the file system mounts.

In short, my goal is to understand how I can access or open a device node from the kernel before the file system mounts.

Comment: This interface is not meant to be used from kernel space. Why do you think you need to move tinymix to the kernel?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My goal is to enable an audio on the Pandaboard from kernel. Now to enable audio I need to set some mixer setting in order to enable the sound path from the module. Now to set a mixer setting I need to access the device node /dev/snd/controlC0 from the kernel. One more thing is I don't want to use the tinymix itself from kernel I just want to replicate the task performed by tinymix in my module.

Comment: Why can't you do this in the machine driver?

Comment: I don't know much about the machine driver(its sdp4430.c) but it will be good if you can explain me that how can i achieve this. One more thing is I have to make this task happen with out changing the existing kernel code. I have to make all the changes in my module only.

Comment: If you don't want to change the kernel, you must use tinymix. And nothing what you said is a reason for not using it.

Comment: But tinymix is a user space utility and of course I have to make a changes in the kernel to set the mixer parameters from the kernel it self. "I can't change a existing kernel code" that means I do not want to disturb the normal operation of the kernel . lets say if I make a change in the machine driver then it may affect the normal operation once the file system gets mounted .So I need to add all the code change to achieve this in my kernel module only.

Comment: (1) I suspect that you’ll have difficulty doing anything with pathnames before the root filesystem is mounted. (2) Do you have the source code of `snd_ctl_open()`? Look at what it does with the arguments. I guess it extracts the device number, `st_rdev`, from the inode, maybe checks the `file` struct for write access, and then calls a lower-level routine. See if you can figure out how to call that lower-level routine directly. (3) If you can’t do that, try just constructing `inode` and `file` structures that contain the information that you need (i.e., the `st_rdev` from `/dev/snd/controlC0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply scott.

I am able to access the device node `/dev/controlC0` as well as able to set the mixer control settings from kernel module. I have followed the below approch.

1. There is one global structure "`static struct snd_minor *snd_minors[SNDRV_OS_MINORS]`"  which is defined in `sound/core/sound.c`. This structure has the information with respect to minor number of all the sound devices.
2. I have found a method to find the device node and file pointer structure from the device minor number. So what I have done is I call a function `find_control_device()` from my driver which in turn iterate for all the devices and check for the `SNDRV_DEVICE_TYPE_CONTROL`(Sound Control Device) device type. Function `find_control_device()` returns the minor number of the control device.
3. From the device minor no I am able to get the device node and file structure information.
4. Once I got the above information I call the `snd_ctl_open()` which will open a device node for the operation.
5. As User space application interact with the kernel space using the IOCTL. To set the mixer setting tinymix calls the `snd_ctl_ioctl()` function. So I have made one wrapper function which will call internally call `snd_ctl_ioctl()` and set the mixer control value.

I have done all the above step in the `module_init` function section in the driver.So as soon as driver gets register in the kernel tree the required tinymix controls are getting set as per the requirement.

I have referred a code of `tinymix.c` from AOSP code tree to manipulate the arguments of the IOCTL.

Thanks,

Hemant